# Function definition on one line

Tags: javascript, coding-style

If we have a function that contains one short statement, what reasons may we consider against putting the function definition on one line?

```
function addTwo(x,y){ return x + y; }
```

vs

```
function addTwo(x,y){
    return x + y;
}
```

The reason I'm asking is that I have scripts with ~100 function definitions, many of which could be one-liners. However, I have doubts whether mixing them with multiline functions will eventually decrease readability.
Reading JS code, I usually see short functions (that would fit well in one line) written on multiple lines, but I have never seen a reason against one-liners.
So, my question addresses those who in such a situation considered using one-liners, and eventually settled for or against it, for a good reason.

Comment: You have to worry (sometimes) in JavaScript about *adding* line breaks, but never about not adding them. (Well that's true if you're using semicolons to separate statements anyway, but that seems obvious.)

Comment: "Is there `any` convention..." is a bad question as nobody will know all coding conventions (e.g., I can just write one which does not allow it). The basic idea behind conventions is to improve readibility and also to prevent people reformat code all the time. - Thus, it depends on what you (and maybe the team in which you work) want and like.

Comment: This is primarily opinion based... IMO. For me it depends on the function's use. If it's a trivial utility that I don't care much about it might go on one line.

Comment: @MrTux that's a good point, thank you. Would it improve the question if I put it this way: "Is it an accepted practise to define functions on one line?"?

Comment: I think in order to improve the question you should ask for pros and cons on doing it in one line or two lines. - It's a question regarding opinions of programmers - it depends on what you (and maybe the team in which you work) want and like. - There are also lots of people discussing where to put the braces... (i.e., you example would have 4 lines instead of the three).

Comment: There is no definitive style guide or convention and as your examples are functionally identical and you are not operating under the conventions of an organisation that enforces them, you are free to do as you see fit.

Comment: Why the downvoting, folks? It's a legitimate question and bothering about the exact phrasing of the question is a little nitpicky, don't you think? It is clear what's being asked.

Comment: I rephrased the question and briefly explained why I'm asking. The original phrasing might have been vague. I hope it's clear enough now, but I'll welcome advices for further improvements, if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Little benefit can be gained from writing it as one line.   Multiple lines are easier to read.  And if functionality needs to be changed, someone doesn't have to reformat it later.

The only real benefit is size of the file to the client. I looked an the difference between them was 2 bytes gzipped.

A best practice, however, would be to minimize and optimize your code with something like closure-compiler for production.   If you did that, then readability wins over size, hands down.

IMHO

Comment: Please stop explaining why and giving them apologies. Just say it is not applicable

Answer (score 3):

There is no clear answer to this question. It's about people's opinion about what is good style (and easy readable/understandable for them).

Take your example

```
function addTwo(x,y){
    return x + y;
}
```

There will also be people saying that this is ugly, because braces should have their own line (e.g., the linux kernel people):

```
function addTwo(x,y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

At the end it's about the context in which you are developing. If you are in a company, then the company might have any coding convention which you have to stick to.

If you have a team you have to have some common agreement on how to style the code in order to prevent "edit wars".

**All in all**, it depends on you, the team or the company to decide what's the style to use. And of course if you want others to use/read/extend/work with your code, you should try to make it easily usable (e.g., omitting spaces or using weird variable names is bad style). - Thus, putting short functions on one line (is|can be) ok, as long as you do it consistent within one project (and the lines won't get to long - however, one could also argue about that).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I rephrased the question, and briefly explained why I care about it. I agree that considerations on coding style are often opinion based. However, these opinions are many times backed by experience of using one style with better effects on the development than the other style. I usually find multiline function definitions even though they would fit well on one line, but I never saw a reasoning against one-liners. This is why I asked.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that it's commonly preferred that you space out and write readable code if you want someone else to read it. Otherwise if you want to optimize your code remove white spaces. This is subjective as it is my opinion.